# PHP: start session only when necessary

Tags: php, session

I have my own Session class, which handles session actions. I wanted to make a mechanism, that the session starts only when it is needed - if no session variables are set, system does not create it.

So that's the code (simplified):

```
class Session
{
  public function __construct()
  {
  }

  protected function startSession($onlyIfExists = false)
  {
    if (session_id() == '')
    {
      if ($onlyIfExists && !isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]))
        return;
      @session_start();
    }
  }

  public function setVar($id, $value)
  {
    $this->startSession();
    $_SESSION[$id] = $value;
  }

  public function getVar($id)
  {
      $this->startSession(true);  //starts session only if the session-id cookie exists (if the session was already started for this user)
      if (isset($_SESSION) && array_key_exists($id, $_SESSION))
        return $_SESSION[$id];
      else return NULL;
  }
}
```

And then I just always have to use this class object to get/set session variables, e.g.:

```
$session = new Session();
$session->getVar('test');  //does not start session at the first time
$session->setVar('test', 1);  //starts session; after refreshing the page the above line does start session (cookie exists) and the value=1 is returned
```

Is it a good solution? Do you see any potential drawbacks, vulnerabilities? Or maybe it is a standard to start session each time?

Because in my application any session variables are created only after authorization, so I don't need session for 99.999% of users.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this because of the cookie laws? If so, just put a note on the site somewhere that says "continued use of this site implies acceptance of our cookie usage" or something to that effect. Start session every time, and BLAM, sorted.

Comment: Actually, starting a session does perform a list of actions inside the server, which may take some time. It may be only a bit, but if it affects 99.999% of users on a really big site, it may be worth the effort. In smaller use cases -- no, it doesn't.

Comment: you should do `session_start();` in every page in action because if you be in a page with no `session_start();` for a while your session will expire I think. and you should also check authorization for any page that would do any part of user's actions like fetching thier data or creat, update or delete.

Comment: Also, why not just keep a `static` boolean inside the session class and start the session when accessing it AND this boolean is false? @imsiso Sessions expire either when the browser closes, or after a specified time (manually set by the programmer, usually 2 weeks or more). Just like a cookie.

Comment: Well, it's not about laws, I thought it would improve performance or something, if the site has e.g. 100K visitors/day... but maybe it doesn't make sense?

Comment: @opatut what? I knew that it would expire with closing and a long time but what about time without having session_start() run ? like don't refreshing page for a long and/or browsing pages without session_start?

Comment: I never heard about that. Why would PHP even care about the session if no session_start was called? The session is just a cookie, and that expires the very moment the browser decides to drop it -- so basically either on tab close or after the expiry date.

Comment: @saq - you should see that what is worth the effort as @ opatut said people use framework that would do lots of works and ran lots of codes and because of that they would use more powerful systems but the are now fell more comfortable in extending it or to using a team to working on it or something.

Comment: @opatut - I'm not sure about what I said but I heard it from a person that I now don't remeber who was it but I remember that he was kind of pro. so I can't say anything right now.

Comment: @opatut - please post an answer for this question to seprate them from unanswered questions.

Comment: @imsiso: There is no problem with session expiry - because if I set e.g. $session->setVar('isAdmin', true) and then check it in each request by $session->getVar('isAdmin'), the session will always start because the condition "if ($onlyIfExists && !isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) return;" will never be positive (cookie has been created after starting session in setVar() method).

Comment: ok but you are asking about pages that we don't need to start a session or why you had write kind of class??!

Comment: @opatut: in practice, session life depends on two independent things: garbage collector configuration set by session.gc_maxlifetime (in short) and cookie with session-id. One of this: killing session by GC or deleting the cookie will destroy session or make it unreachable. So if I don't update session file by session_start(), after some time it will be seen by GC as a garbage and may be cleaned.
But as I said, the session will be started each time after setting any session variable.

Comment: @imsiso: yes, but in e.g. index.php there must be a condition like checking if user is an admin, and then to decide which scripts/templates to load; if session was not created this checking by getVar() won't start session, if you had used setVar() previously (to set e.g. 'isAdmin' to true) - it will start it, but then it means that you are an administrator and that's the goal

Comment: @saq but you cannot really influence the GC by calling session_start() more often, can you? I mean, you should configure the server so that no session is collected before you want it, e.g. if only one users uses the site and waits 30 minutes between page refresh, it should still be there (usually). So while indeed start_session() may refresh this timer, this is rather a hack to keep it "probably" alive than a good control over your session expiry.

Comment: @saq - my English is not so good just one sentence.Please use `session_start();` in every page cause many people and frameworks are using it.

Comment: @opatut: well that is the matter a little bit far from this subject... generally that's the general way to maintain session - refreshing. Google accounts have dealed with this by setting lifetime to infinity, you can also make a simple JS script which performs an AJAX call each e.g. 10 minutes to keep the session alive while user has his browser open. There is no other way.

Comment: and I should add another thing in a real site we really would not have a page without session_start(); as in this site. cause we always need to auth or remembering things in a single request like forms buy basket , ... and also in a page like about we would have need a link to panel that should be shown just to users and ...

Comment: you're right , and I should add when I was at your age(just kidding (-:) I remember that I was trying to optimize session_stat and I should add that I had found ajax way as you said. but what you really looking for just seprating `session_start();` put it in another file and write a code to call ir seprately? or performance or ...  . But I should tell you something but I don't know how much you are experienced but you would not be able to start driving if you said I want to learn everything first.And you should think about a problem and spend tome and energy on it if it really matters.

Comment: @imsiso: that was just a semi-theoretical issue to solve, but as you both said it's not worth to implement - the profits are quite blurry

Comment: @saq - now if you get your answer please accept @ opatut's answer toseprate this question from unanswered question's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vulnerabilities: none, I guess. Pretty easy code, not much to go wrong.

Drawbacks: except for more code, none, really.

Advantanges: only in very highly used systems with a few authorized users. Really, starting a session is not that big of a deal, compared to things like Database queries and content compiling. Usually, I would not see a need to optimize this. Just start a session every time, or just on the relevant pages (e.g. if you have a few backend pages that do require auth, just start the session there). Except, of course, you deal with thousands of users per second. I measured a simple `session_start()` to take about 0.1ms.

Improvements: as zerkms suggests below, starting the session if the cookie exists, or the site wants to write to the session would be the easiest and bulletproof way to manage this and not spawn useless sessions.

Comment: Actually the criteria could be easier: if there is a session cookie - start session implicitly. Start it explicitly on a login page (or on any page that starts writing to session)

Comment: +1 to @opatut - most thing I wanted to say are things you said.

Comment: @zerkms You are right, that would be way easier, and more consistent. I will edit the post :)